# How to reference .Release.name or helper function of one subchart in another subchart?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, templating

I have one parent chart with three subcharts: subchart01, subchart02, subchart-main. In my subchart-main, I have a configmap.yaml template that needs to create a json string based on other subcharts:

**configmap.yaml**:

```
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  appsettings.json: |-
    {
      "Services": [
        {
          "Name": {{ .Values.service1.name }}
          "Endpoint": "{{ .Values.service1.endpoint }}:5080"
        },
        {
          "Name": {{ .Values.service2.name }}
          "Endpoint": "{{ .Values.service2.endpoint }}:5081"
        },
      ]
    }
```

Then I have the following values.yaml file in the parent chart folder but it didn't work.

**values.yaml**:

```
subchart-main:
  service1:
    name: {{ template .Release.name .Subcharts.subchart01 }}
    endpoint: {{ template "subchart01.fullname" .Subcharts.subchart01 }}
  service2:
    name: {{ template .Release.name .Subcharts.subchart02 }}
    endpoint: {{ template "subchart02.fullname" .Subcharts.subchart02 }}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### Important

As mentioned in the [official documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/) a sub-chart

1. A subchart is considered "stand-alone", which means a subchart can never explicitly depend on its parent chart.
2. For that reason, a subchart cannot access the values of its parent.
3. A parent chart can override values for subcharts.
4. Helm has a concept of global values that can be accessed by all charts.

### What you can do

You can use `global` values and pass as values the helm template syntax ( `{{ .Values.global.example }}`) to the sub-charts.

Therefore, within the values.yaml file of the main-chart you can control and overwrite and share all values, while the sub-charts remain independent.

#### Code

You can find the complete example on github: https://github.com/Hadsch/helm-share-values-demo

*mychart/Chart.yaml*

```
  apiVersion: v2
  name: mychart
```

*mychart/values.yaml*
myValue: value-for-parent

```
global:
  service1:
    # Define name and endpoint for service1
    name: "my-service-1 SHARED"
    endpoint: "my-service-1-endpoint SHARED"
  service2:
    # Define name and endpoint for service1
    name: "my-service-2"
    endpoint: "my-service-2-endpoint"

subchart-main:
  service1:
    # Pass the values from global.service1 to subchart-main as a "string" using the template syntax
    name: "{{ .Values.global.service1.name }}"
    endpoint: "{{ .Values.global.service1.endpoint }}"

subchart01:
  # Pass the values from global.service1 to subchart01 as a "string" using the template syntax
  name: "{{ .Values.global.service1.name }}"
  endpoint: "{{ .Values.global.service1.endpoint }}"
```

*mychart/charts/subchart-main/Charts.yaml*

```
apiVersion: v2
name: subchart-main
```

*mychart/charts/subchart-main/values.yaml*

**IMPORTANT:** These values will be overwritten by the one defined in `mychart/values.yaml` if installed as sub-chart. If installed independently the values defined here will be used.

```
service1:
  name: "My Service 1"
  endpoint: "My Service 1 endpoint"

service2:
  name: "My Service 2"
  endpoint: "My Service 2 endpoint"
```

*mychart/charts/subchart-main/templates/subchart-main.yaml*

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-cfg-subchart-main
data:
  # Important: The values containing the template syntax. Therefore the template function is required to get the defined values in the global section.
  name: {{ tpl .Values.service1.name . }}
  endpoint: {{ tpl .Values.service1.endpoint . }}
```

*mychart/charts/subchart01/values.yaml*

Same as subchart-main: The values will be overwritten!

```
name: "subchart-01"
endpoint: "subchart-01-endpoint"
```

*mychart/charts/subchart01/templates/subchart01-cfg.yaml*

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-cfg-subchart01
data:
  name: {{ tpl .Values.name . }}
  endpoint: {{ tpl .Values.endpoint . }}
```

#### Output from my test run

```
$ helm install my-test --dry-run mychart
NAME: my-test
NAMESPACE: my-test-namespace
STATUS: pending-install
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
HOOKS:
MANIFEST:
---
# Source: mychart/charts/subchart-main/templates/subchart-main.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-test-cfg-subchart-main
data:
  name: my-service-1 SHARED
  endpoint: my-service-1-endpoint SHARED
---
# Source: mychart/charts/subchart01/templates/subchart01-cfg.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-test-cfg-subchart01
data:
  name: my-service-1 SHARED
  endpoint: my-service-1-endpoint SHARED
---
# Source: mychart/templates/parent.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-test-cfg-parent
data:
  my-value: value-for-parent
```